# If limit of two sequences converges, do the sequences converge too?

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, analysis

We assume that $a_n\neq b_n$ and $a_n\neq \frac{1}{b_n}$, and we know $\frac{a_n}{b_n}$ converges to the limit $1$ (in other words $\lim_{n\to\infty}\big(\frac{a_n}{b_n}\big)=1$).

This means that $\frac{\lim_{n\to\infty}(a_n)}{\lim_{n\to\infty}(b_n)}=1$ and thus $\lim_{n\to\infty}(a_n)=\lim_{n\to\infty}(b_n)$.

Can we now assume that both of these sequences converge, in particular to a same limit $L$? Can we say $$\exists L\in\mathbb{R}\Rightarrow \lim_{n\to\infty}(a_n)=L=\lim_{n\to\infty}(b_n)?$$

Comment: Most certainly not!! Given any sequence $z \in \left(\mathbb{C^{\times}}\right)^{\mathbb{N}}$ of nonzero complex numbers it is the case $\frac{z_n}{z_n} \xrightarrow{n \to \infty} 1$ without however that having anything to mean about the original sequence $z$, which can be as wild and pathological as possible. If aside from the condition that the sequence of ratios converge to $1$ one makes the additional assumption that the numerator or denominator sequence converge to a nonzero number *only then* could one infer that the sequence on the other side of the fraction converges to the same limit.

Comment: Even if you know that $a_n, b_n$ are bounded you can still have them diverge (oscillate) i.e take $a_n=2+(-1)^n,b_n=a_n+\frac1n$.

Comment: You recieved 2 answers to your question. Is any of them what you needed? If so, consider *accepting* the best answer and upvoting all useful answers you got. That's how the site works.

Answer (score 7):

I dont think they even need to converge take $a_n = n +1 $ and $b_n = n $

Answer (score 2):

Take any sequence $c_n$ that converges to $1$.

Now the ratio of the sequences $a_n:=b_nc_n$ and $b_n$ obviously tends to $1$ regardless the convergence of $a_n$ and $b_n$.

But if they do converge, the converge to the same limit.